# Fix up and normalize data set

Tags: r, statistics, data-science

I would like to use a repeatability test for normalized data (Rtpr for Gaussian data). However, I cannot figure out how to normally distribute my data set, as it is strongly skewed, and most values converge into one large column when looking into the histogram (very similar value numbers for most individuals, as seen in the picture below).

[image]

I used the most known data transformation techniques, but none seems to work (square root, cube, log, log10, reciprocal and Box-Cot). I know I am missing something, but I am quite new to statistics and transformation/ normalization, so I am unsure what I am doing wrong.

Here is the code I used with the data sets:
https://github.com/SoundsF1shy/Normalise-data-set

Thank you, and have a great day.

Comment: Hi SoundsF1shy, this seems to be a [statistics] or [data-science] question rather than a practical issue with [r] language. You're more likely to get targeted answers under the corresponding tags.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. I did add new tags!